# Python Find All Children And Grandchildren

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a SQL query that finds me all ingredients needed for a recipe.

| Parent | Child | Variation | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza Margherita | pizza dough | 1 | -1 |
| Pizza Margherita | tomato sauce with pork | 1 | -1 |
| Pizza Margherita | pizza dough | 2 | -1 |
| Pizza Margherita | tomato sauce with beef | 2 | -1 |
| pizza dough | flour | 1 | -2 |
| pizza dough | water | 1 | -2 |
| pizza dough | flour | 1 | -2 |
| pizza dough | water | 1 | -2 |
| tomato sauce with pork | tomato sauce | 1 | -3 |
| tomato sauce with pork | pork | 1 | -3 |
| tomato sauce with beef | tomato sauce | 1 | -3 |
| tomato sauce with beef | beef | 1 | -3 |

A Pizza Margherita might have more than one recipes (or variations in my case), and the recipes could share the same children.

**I need to transform my SQL result:**

```
_content = [
  ('Pizza Margherita', 'pizza dough', 1, -1),
  ('Pizza Margherita', 'tomato sauce with pork', 1, -1),
  ('Pizza Margherita', 'pizza dough', 2, -1),
  ('Pizza Margherita', 'tomato sauce with beef', 2, -1),
  (...so on and so forth)
]
```

**to a python dictionary that looks like this:**

[image]

If the children were of same variation, they would be put under a dictionary
{"pseudo": True, "children": [{ "text: {"name": "child_of_variation_1"}, "children": [] }, { "text: {"name": "another_child_of_variation_1"}, "children": [other children] }]

Could anyone please suggest a more Pythonic way of transforming a list of tuples to a dictionary?

Comment: *"Could anyone please suggest a more Pythonic way of solving this?"* What is "this"? You presented your data, but what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

My underperforming attempt:

```
master = {"text": {"name": master_name, "data-level": 0}, "children": []}

def find_children(parent_dict):
    children_container = []

    for i, _row in enumerate(_content):
        parent, child, variation, level = _row
        item_dict = {"text": {"name": child, "data-level": level, "data-variation": variation},
                     "children": []
                     }

        if level + 1 == parent_dict["text"]["data-level"] \
                and str(parent).lower() == str(parent_dict["text"]["name"]).lower() \
                and _row not in children_container:

            item_dict["children"] = find_children(item_dict)
            if item_dict not in children_container:
                children_container.append(item_dict)

    # ! - group children by variation then put under same pseudo dict
    variations = set(map(lambda x: x["text"]["data-variation"], children_container))
    new_children_container = [
        {"pseudo": True,
         "children": [y for y in children_container if y["text"]["data-variation"] == x]} for x in variations
    ]
    return new_children_container

master["children"] = find_children(master)
```

It succeeded only when dealing with a small list. It stuck when the result is greater than 1000 rows.